# URL Rewrite in Apache + Tomcat set up with change in web application context

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, tomcat6, redirection, url-routing

How to make URL 
http:/hostname:8080/abc?func=ll point to the URL
http:/hostname:8080/xyz?func=ll automatically.

Set up is Apache behind which Tomcat is present.
Application "xyz" is deployed on Tomcat. Application abc is non existent.

All requests go to tomcat via Apache only.
All opinions are valued and welcomed. Please help

Regards
Abinash

Comment: Do you *really* need to change the context path? It makes life a lot more difficult. Why not deploy the app under /abc on Tomcat?